# How do I change the default value of the “position” category attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products

I would like to update the default position value that products are assigned when they are added to a category.

When you create/update a category from the categories editor, new products are saved with a position of 0.

What I want to do is have items save with a position of 100 instead of 1.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of it? In which version of Magento you want to achieve the same?

Comment: My Magento is 1.9.2.
I want to do this because everytime I create a new category and I want to sort the products, I have to change all the positions to 100 (or another number different than 0) to realocate the products that I want to show first with a lower number of position.

Comment: You can assign 100 position to product while product creation, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method or event to change this. If you want to change default value you can rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts`

```
/**
 * Add products to category
 */
if (!empty($insert)) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($insert as $productId => $position) {
        $data[] = array(
            'category_id' => (int)$id,
            'product_id'  => (int)$productId,
            // changed code
            // 'position'    => (int)$position
            'position'    => (int)$position ? (int)$position : 100
        );
    }
    $adapter->insertMultiple($this->_categoryProductTable, $data);
}
```

This should set position to 100 if you do not enter a value.

Comment: Thanks this save my time file 1.9.2.4 path is app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php Line No 342, it's better to copy this file to local an edit, if you wish to upgrade Magento version in future

Comment: I notice this not work when product assign to a category via product edit page category tree, anyone know a solution for that  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241188/magento-add-position-999-when-assign-product-to-category

Answer (score 1):

You can work with negative position numbers too - i.e. since all your products have set `position = 0` by default just set those you want to have displayed before them to `position = -1`.