# Magento add position 999 when assign product to category

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm using Magento 1.9.x and trying to change default position number of products.

Ex, when we assign product to category via product page i need to set it to 999 position

[image]

I changed default **position** field value of **catalog_category_product** table

[image]

But nothing changed.

i changed `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category.php`

```
/**
         * Add products to category
         */
        if (!empty($insert)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($insert as $productId => $position) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => (int)$id,
                    'product_id'  => (int)$productId,
                    'position'    =>  (int)$position ? (int)$position : 999
                );
            }
            //(int)$position
            $adapter->insertMultiple($this->_categoryProductTable, $data);
        }
```

but it only effect when adding products to category via category page.

anyone know a solution for this please, Thank You

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example module, which only sets the position for new categories added when a product has been saved (or all categories if it's a new product).  This doesn't include category save events but a similar principal can be followed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate here,

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource
```

Open `Product.php`, find function name `_saveCategories`

You will find the d following array within that file.

```
$data[] = array(
    'category_id' => (int)$categoryId,
    'product_id'  => (int)$object->getId(),
    'position'    => 1  
);
```

Replace `$data` array with following one.

```
$data[] = array(
    'category_id' => (int)$categoryId,
    'product_id'  => (int)$object->getId(),
    'position'    => 999
);
```

Additional Note:
Go here, `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource`, Open `Category.php`
Find `_saveCategoryProducts()` method name, and looking for the following code.

This will work from category pages in add assign mode.

```
/**
* Add products to category
*/
if (!empty($insert)) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($insert as $productId => $position) {
        $position = 999; //Added this line
        $data[] = array(
            'category_id' => (int)$id,
            'product_id'  => (int)$productId,
            'position'    => (int)$position
        );
    }
    $adapter->insertMultiple($this->_categoryProductTable, $data);
}
```

This will work from category pages in update assign mode.

```
/**
* Update product positions in category
*/
if (!empty($update)) {
    foreach ($update as $productId => $position) {
        $position = 999; //Added this line
        $where = array(
            'category_id = ?'=> (int)$id,
            'product_id = ?' => (int)$productId
        );
        $bind  = array('position' => (int)$position);
        $adapter->update($this->_categoryProductTable, $bind, $where);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is forbidden to update the Magento core files !

Comment: @sandip can i know the megento version above you used, i checked on my magento 1.9 version but cannot find that kind of functions

Comment: @SunethKalhara Magento version is 1.9.3

Comment: very strange i'm using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 but can't see  _saveCategories on /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php

Comment: search in `/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php` not in `Product.php`

Comment: Do NOT do this, never ever edit the core files, at the very least, copy the file into the local codepool (copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php`), or better, create a custom module and rewrite that particular class

Comment: Yes once you found function then you can put those files in local codepool

Comment: this worked fine, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new module.. Its working fine. I tested it.

Let's call it Product_Position.

app/etc/modules/Product_Position.xml - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Position>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Product_Position>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Product/Position/etc/config.xml - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Position>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Product_Position>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <position>
                <class>Product_Position_Model</class>
            </position>
        </models>       
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <product_position>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Product_Position_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setPosition</method>
                    </product_position>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Product/Position/Model/Observer.php - the observe class

```
<?php

class Product_Position_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function setPosition($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId();
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); //get an instance of the core resource
        $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product');
        $sql = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET `position` = 999 WHERE `product_id` = {$id}"; //set the position for the product in all the categories.
        $connection->query($sql);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will set every position to 999 whenever the product is saved, which wasn't what was asked, also it's very bad practice to run direct SQL queries

Comment: @eddhall , You can customize code for add required position in observer. Also if you see code in question then you can see "999" written is static. You are Welcome. :)

Comment: OP asked for a product to be set to 999 when a product is assigned to a category, the module you have written changes the position of a product in every category to 999 whenever it has been saved, regardless of whether the product is new in that category or not - it is wrong

Comment: @eddhall , so you are welcome to make changes in Answer for help in more specified way in prospect of question.

Comment: I have done so, my answer now contains a full and tested module to do what the original question asked, without using direct SQL queries

Comment: @eddhall. cool :)

Comment: @ChiragRajput i got a little issue with this when i disable and enable product it change the position to 999 is there anyway to fix that, thanks a lot

Comment: @SunethKalhara , Are you only changing the status from admin only and issue happen?

Comment: @ChiragRajput yes i'm changing it from admin product edit page

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be to:

1. Create a custom module
2. Create an observer on the `catalog_product_save_before` event, using it to set a flag in the registry (something like `Mage::register('new_product_for_positioning', 'yes');` if the product is new, or saving the products before-save category IDs to the registry to compare after
3. Create an observer on the `catalog_product_save_after` event, fetching the products category ids if the product is new, or comparing the after-save category IDs to the before save ones (that you saved in the registry)
4. Iterate through each category ID, and change the product's position in there.

Edit:  Module code:

app/etc/modules/Product_Position.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Position>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Product_Position>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Product/Position/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_Position>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Product_Position>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <position>
                <class>Product_Position_Model</class>
            </position>
        </models>       
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- set flags for new product or new categories -->
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <product_position_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>product_position/observer</class>
                        <method>setFlags</method>
                    </product_position_before>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>

            <!-- use previously set flags to change product position -->
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <product_position_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>product_position/observer</class>
                        <method>setPosition</method>
                    </product_position_before>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Product/Position/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Product_Position_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Check before a product save, if it is new, or record pre-save cateogory IDs if it is not
     * 
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     *
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     */
    public function setFlags (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        if($product->getId()===null){
            Mage::register('new_product_for_positioning', 'yes');
        }else{
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
            Mage::register('categories_before_update'.$product->getId(), $categoryIds);
        }
    }

    /**
     * If a product is new, update position for all categorys
     * If a product is not new, compare pre-save category IDs to post save ones, and update positioning for new ids
     * 
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPosition(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        if (Mage::registry('new_product_for_positioning') == 'yes') {
            Mage::unregister('new_product_for_positioning');

            if (count($categoryIds) > 0) {
                foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
                    $this->_updateProductPosition($categoryId, $product->getId());
                }
            }

            return $this; //Don't need to do any more after this
        }

        $categoriesBeforeSave = Mage::registry('categories_before_update' . $product->getId());
        if (is_array($categoryIds) && count($categoryIds) > 0) {
            Mage::unregister('categories_before_update' . $product->getId());

            $categoriesForUpdate = array_diff($categoryIds, $categoriesBeforeSave);

            if (is_array($categoriesForUpdate) && count($categoriesForUpdate) > 0) {
                foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
                    $this->_updateProductPosition($categoryId, $product->getId());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get category, get category positions, update for specific product
     * 
     * @param $categoryId
     * @param $productId
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _updateProductPosition($categoryId, $productId) {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

        if (!$category->getId()) { //do nothing as category somehow doesn't exist
            return;
        }

        //$newPosition = $category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem()->getData('position') + 1;
        //use the above to place product last in category, or the below to set to 999
        $newPosition = 999;

        $positions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);

        if (is_array_key($productId, $positions)) {
            $positions[$productId] = $newPosition;
        }

        $category->setData('products_position', $positions);

        $category->save();
    }
}
```